# generate an urn/iri/uri dynamically

Tags: sparql

I need to generate dynamically the name of a graph depending on the time.
I've tough that some think like

```
select ?g where { 
    bind(concat("<urn:myNewGraph_",str(now()),">") as ?g)
}
```

would have done the trick, but with Stardog I get a null result.

If instead I run this

```
select ?g where { 
    bind(concat("urn:myNewGraph_",str(now())) as ?g)
}
```

i get `urn:myNewGraph_2015-05-28T09:37:11.823Z`

Any Ideas?

moreover I'm not sure that even if i can get somehow a string like `<urn:myNewGraph_2015-05-28T09:37:11.823Z>` would have worked as a valid argument for a graph name as can be seen from this not-working test:

```
INSERT {graph ?g {<urn:s> <urn:p> <urn:o>}
where { 
    ?g="<rn:myNewGraph_2015-05-28T09:37:11.823Z>"
}
```

is there a proper way to generate an urn/iri/uri dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original query looks correct, and produces a valid result when I execute it using a different SPARQL engine (Sesame), so I guess that you might want to report this to the Stardog developers as a possible bug.

However, to be able to use the value thus obtained it needs to be an actual URI (or IRI) - whereas what you're producing is a literal string.

You need to change two things: first of all, get rid of the enclosing `<` and `>` (these brackets are not actually part of the IRI) - so actually your second query is better. Second, use the `IRI` function to convert your string value to an IRI:

```
INSERT {GRAPH ?g {<urn:s> <urn:p> <urn:o>} }
WHERE { 
     BIND( IRI(CONCAT("urn:myNewGraph_",STR(NOW()))) as ?g)
}
```

Not sure it's necessary in your case, but in general you may need to use the `ENCODE_FOR_URI` function in there somewhere, to make sure that any special characters in your string are properly encoded/escaped before turning it into an IRI.

Comment: is probably a stardog problem because with your solution I get this error: `Graph_",STR(NOW())) as ?g))} Expecting ')', got 'AS' `

Comment: that may have been a result of me incorrectly closing parentheses. I think I fixed it now.