# Create durable IRIs within SPARQL CONSTRUCT?

Tags: sparql

I have been asked to work with some triples that are very flat and which have information about their objects embedded in their predicates.  Put another way, almost all of the predicates will be `owl:DatatypeProperties`.

```
:meeting1 :hasChair "Professor Gadget" .
:meeting1 :chairPhoneNumber "555-1212" .
:meeting1 :hasAttendee "William Gosset" .
```

My team has been thinking about semantically expanding the triples.  I think this will require creating new entities/`rdf:Resource`s/`owl:Thing`s.  If I have a choice, I would prefer to create IRIs based on UUIDs (as opposed to using blank nodes.)

```
:meeting1 a :meeting .
:meeting1 :hasChair :ABC123 .
:meeting1 :hasAttendee :DEF999 .
:ABC123 a :person .
:ABC123 :name "Professor Gadget" .
:ABC123 :phoneNumber  "555-1212" .
:DEF999  a :person .
:DEF999  :name "William Gosset" .
```

I know I can say

```
CONSTRUCT { ?m a :meeting } WHERE { ?m :hasChair ?c }
```

How can I say that "Professor Gadget" must be the `:name` of some `:person`, and that the same `:person` has `:phoneNumber`  "555-1212"?

[generate an urn/iri/uri dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503255/generate-an-urn-iri-uri-dynamically) shows how to `BIND` a constructed URI to a SPARQL variable and `INSERT` it.  Furthermore, I know that I can create a UUID with `STRUUID()`.  Will I be able to do that within an `INSERT` subquery within a `CONSTRUCT` statement?  I would want the URI for Professor Gadget to persist across the meeting-chairing statement, the `:phoneNumber` statement, and the `:name` statement, but I would want fresh UUIDs for people with different names, or who chaired meetings other than `:meeting1`, etc.  I would rather risk assigning multiple UUIDs to Professor Gadget than potentially using the same UUID to refer to multiple meeting chairpersons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what have so far.  I think this is what I want, but still open to suggestions.

Additional triples with prefix:

```
prefix : <http://example.com/>
:meeting2 :hasChair "James Moriarty" .
:meeting2 :chairPhoneNumber "unlisted" .
:meeting2 :hasAttendee "William Gosset" .
```

Construct statement:

```
prefix : <http://example.com/>
CONSTRUCT 
{ 
    ?m a :meeting .
    ?m :hasChair ?u .
    ?u :name ?c
}
    WHERE { ?m :hasChair ?c .
    bind (URI(concat("http://example.com/",STRUUID())) as ?u)}
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|                subject                 | predicate  |                 object                 |
+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|  :09dfb998-cc34-48d3-830e-e480f09e94ba | :name      | "James Moriarty"^^xsd:string           |
|  :323b0c9c-0b07-4f32-abb6-503c1d97d80e | :name      | "Professor Gadget"^^xsd:string         |
|  :meeting1                             | :hasChair  | :323b0c9c-0b07-4f32-abb6-503c1d97d80e  |
|  :meeting1                             | rdf:type   | :meeting                               |
|  :meeting2                             | :hasChair  | :09dfb998-cc34-48d3-830e-e480f09e94ba  |
|  :meeting2                             | rdf:type   | :meeting                               |
+----------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What if `:meeting1 :hasChair "Professor Gadget"` and `:meeting3 :hasChair "Professor Gadget"`? STRUUID() generates different UUIDs for every result. I think, you need something like `URI(concat("http://example.com/", MD5(?c))) as ?u`

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks. One of the goals of the project is to resolve multiple ids for one entity in reality, so this may not be necessary.  Otherwise, I would agree that MD5() would be a best practice.